# Select second recipe from API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using $.get to define an array of recipes from an API.

```
var recipes = $.get( "http://api.punchfork.com/recipes?key=11223344&q=lamb" )
```

APL Looks like...

```
{
  "count": 10, 
  "recipes": [
    {
      "rating": 67.4457, 
      "source_name": "Simply Recipes", 
      "source_img": "http://simplyrecipes.com/photos/spicy-lamb-stew-520.jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "rating": 65.2406, 
      "source_name": "Simply Recipes", 
      "source_img": "http://simplyrecipes.com/photos/lamb-stew-orig.jpg"
    }]
```

I want to call results using something like.

```
recipes[1].rating
```

But because the API has ...

```
{
  "count": 10, 
  "recipes": [
```

... at the beginning I cannot.

How would I select the second rating using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```
recipes.recipes[1].rating
```

Isn't it? (But better call your variable differently)

P.S. Probably not correct, could you explain your question more if so, please?

Answer (score -1):

JSON Syntax Rules

1. Data is in name/value pairs
2. Data is separated by comma
3. Curly brackets holds objects
4. Square brackets holds arrays

[reference](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)

hope it helps you to figure out how to access an object within array in JSON.

Comment: -1, this is entirely unhelpful.  The JSON data has already been decoded, the question is about how to reach an element from in it within Javascript.  Also, stop linking to w3schools, as it is a hive of out of date information and bad practices.

Comment: @Charles do you want me to provide a full code to OP? I am just to help him to move a head instead.